# Simulation Run gets stuck in Anylogic Material Handling Library

Tags: anylogic

[image]

I am using Material Handling Library. I have the following resources,

[image]

And also, I am noticing there are some blocks that have seized resources, agent has also entered retrieve block, but its stuck there.

[image]

Is it something related to how my storage is storing products???? or Could it possibly be paths, because I am using one way paths? Or could it be nodes, some nodes seems intertwisted?

Comment: You will need to figure this out yourself, very hard to help. Always build models in tiny steps: Add a feature, testtesttest. All works fine? Add another TINY feature and repeat. In this way, you will always know what caused an issue ;) Now, all you can do is strip back bit by bit to find the root cause, tbh